# Ruby loop until set time and if the condition return false then raise and exception

Tags: ruby

I am trying to loop until 10 seconds and if returns within 10 seconds true then break the loop. If returns false after 10 seconds then raise an exception.

```rb
1.upto(2) do
  loop do
    if current_status == db_status
      break
    else !current_status == db_status
      raise 'status is incorrect'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you want to ask about?

Comment: You can return a value and raise an exception at the same time. What's the expected output?

Comment: but don't you want `elsif !current_status == db_status` ?

Comment: `current_status == db_status` will either return `true` or `false`, there is not third option. Therefore the `loop` doesn't make sense and the loop would always return in the first iteration – either because of the `break` or with an exception. Furthermore `else` doesn't take an argument... Can you please elaborate and clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the `1.upto(2)` part, but from your description I'm guessing this is what you are trying to accomplish, right?

```rb
start = Time.now
while (Time.now - start) < 10 do
  break if current_status == db_status
end
raise 'status is incorrect' unless current_status == db_status
```

Comment: @dansek, you're trying to edit `db_status` into `status`. That doesn't make sense. Your example is clearly using `db_status` variable.